# Spring Web App in Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, spring, cloud

I have developed a Spring Web Application and successfully tested in my local in Tomcat 7. Below are the technology stack

1. JDK 7
2. Spring 4
3. MongoDB
4. MySQL

I have created Cloudfoundy Webservice account, imported mysql and mongodb services. When I push my application to Cloudfoundry there is no application specific error in the console but I received following log

> Wed May 20 2015 19:40:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) [DEA] ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
>   Wed May 20 2015 19:40:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) [API] OUT App instance exited with guid b56cb55f-eb35-47e8-9c94-70be6c1fbae1 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"b56cb55f-eb35-47e8-9c94-70be6c1fbae1", "version"=>"30e2fae4-c3a1-4ba8-8f29-b450169e2346", "instance"=>"5b742ce306904654a06e91200ec8a4ce", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>148, "exit_description"=>**"failed to accept connections within health check timeout"**, "crash_timestamp"=>1432131050}

And after that application crashes. Could you please help me or let me know how to get the actual reason for the crash.

Comment: how much memory have you allocated for your app?

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to compatibility issues with JDK 8 and Tomcat 8. So I downgraded the application to JDK 7 and Tomcat 7 using following environment variables

```
env:
    JBP_CONFIG_TOMCAT: '[tomcat: { version: 7.0.+ }]'
    SPRING_PROFILES_DEFAULT: cloud
    JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE: '[version: 1.7.0_+]'
```